# Circular Motion of a bucket

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When a bucket attached to a string is whirled in a vertical circle , why it doesn't fall down when at the top most point because no "real" forces are acting on it in the upward direction and please explain from inertial frame of reference

Comment: Take a look at: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494955/what-is-the-reason-behind-water-not-falling-from-a-bucket-at-the-top-of-loop

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks